# filter nested object array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to sort the above given array so that the output array will be as given in output section. I have tried some code which is given below.  I am using javascript for sorting. In angular I am using this To display menu according to user role.
I have googled a lot but not getting solution

```
this.items = [
      {
        label: 'Home', routerLink: ['Home']
      },
      {
        label: 'menu1',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'submenu1',
            routerLink: '/submenu1'
          },
          {
            label: 'submenu2'
            , routerLink: '/submenu2'
          },
          {
            label: 'submenu3',
            routerLink: ['/submenu3']
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'menu2',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'submenu5',
            routerLink: ['/submenu5']
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'menu3',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'submenu6',
            routerLink: ['/submenu6'],
          }
        ]
      },

    ];
```

output:

```
this.items = [
      {
        label: 'Home', routerLink: ['Home']
      },
      {
        label: 'menu1',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'submenu1',
            routerLink: '/submenu1'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: 'menu3',
        items: [
          {
            label: 'submenu6',
            routerLink: ['/submenu6'],
          }
        ]
      },

    ];
```

code for sorting:

```
let filterArr = this.filteredArray
      .filter(x => x.label == "Home" && x.label == "menu3")
      .map(y => y.items.filter(z => z.label == 'submenu6'));
```

Comment: "sort" != "filter", do you want to filter, sort, or both? Your code only filters (and then maps).

Comment: I want to sort the above

Comment: You want to sort *what* above? The first structure or the second? Separately, I don't see how your code could possibly be turning the first thing above into the second, it maps things to filtered arrays of items.

Comment: The first structure, so that the output will look like second

Comment: @sam based on which criteria?

Comment: Are you filtering the labels in alphabetical order, or what specifically?

Comment: based on the condition give in "code for sorting" above

Comment: @Sam You should edit your question for more clearly

Comment: @ Simeon, the filtering is based in the outher item label and inner item label ie when the outer label is Home && Home and inner item labe is submenu6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the wanted menu and submenu labels into arrays and filter the objects by creating new object with filtered `menus`.

This approach does not mutate the data.

It uses [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for the outer array and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for getting the wanted parts of the nested array.

If the nested array does not have any item, then take the original object.

```js
var items = [{ label: 'Home', routerLink: ['Home'] }, { label: 'menu1', items: [{ label: 'submenu1', routerLink: '/submenu1' }, { label: 'submenu2', routerLink: '/submenu2' }, { label: 'submenu3', routerLink: ['/submenu3'] }] }, { label: 'menu2', items: [{ label: 'submenu5', routerLink: ['/submenu5'] }] }, { label: 'menu3', items: [{ label: 'submenu6', routerLink: ['/submenu6'] }] }],
    menu = ['Home', 'menu1', 'menu3'],
    submenu = ['submenu1', 'submenu6'],
    result = items.flatMap(o => {
        if (!menu.includes(o.label)) return [];
        var items = (o.items || []).filter(({ label }) => submenu.includes(label));
        return items.length ? { ...o, items } : o;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```